# jquery function plugin with return value like $.get in ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, function, plugins

I'm real new to jquery plugins. I want to create a function plugin which have a parameter function that return something to user just like what $.get works.
These are my codes I have tried out

```
(function($) {

    $.fn.myfunc = function(options) {
        if (typeof options === 'undefined') {
            options = {};
        }
        return this;
    };

    $.myfunc = function(options, e) {
        // Default options

        var settings = $.extend({}, $.myfunc.options, {
            anotherfunc: function(a) {
                //
            }
        }, options);
    };

    /**
     * Globally definable rules
     */
    $.myfunc.options = {
        param1: "",
        param2: '',
    }
})(jQuery);
```

I want to achieve this after calling my plugin

```
test = function() {
     $.myfunc({
         param1: "my first param",
         param2: 'my second one',
         anotherfunc: function(data) {
             alert(data); //return something from my plugin
         }
     });
};
$(document).ready(test);
```

I have google and regoogle for hours now . Any help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you're trying to achieve is to add a static method to your plugin the way to go is just add it like you would to a normal object.

```
(function ($) {

    // Define our base to add to
    $.myNameSpace = {};

    //static
    $.myNameSpace.hello = function () {
        console.log("HELLO");
    };
})(jQuery);
```

You'd then invoke it as you'd do with any other jQuery static method:

```
$.myNameSpace.hello();
```

I suggest that you have a look at this [recipe](https://www.inkling.com/read/jquery-cookbook-cody-lindley-1st/chapter-12/recipe-12-8)

Hope it helps.

**EDIT**

I've come up with this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tjkhcve5/28/). It might give you some ideas.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks, but what I need is to get result from the plugin. That static method seems not to work as I need. Can't I be able to achieve like this anotherfunc(data){ alert(data); } ?

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question correctly, If you want to return something from the plugin you need to return that ***something*** (from the question I couldn't understand what do you want to return from the plugin) from the constructor function like this

```
$.myfunc = function(options, e) {
    // Default options

    var settings = $.extend({}, $.myfunc.options, {
        anotherfunc: function(a) {
            //
        }
    }, options);

    return /*something*/; // here
};
```

what happens in the `ajax` internally is, *putting it simplified for understanding, but more technical stuffs goes in actual implementation*

```
$.ajax = function (options) {
    var def = $.Deferred(); // something like this

    var settings = $.extend({}, $.ajax.options, options); // possibly not exactly

    // some more technical stuffs go here

    return def.promise(); // jQuery XHR object which implements the promise interface
};
```

[ajax source ref](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js#L374)

Comment: Thanks, but I have return something in constructor for testing but nothing happened ? Is there any best way?

Comment: @EphraimSwilla what do you mean by returned something? I can't see anything that you return from the constructor function.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have got an answer with simple function, though it is not much as I once wanted

```
test = function() {
        var param = {
            param1: 'hello world', // list of phone numbers to send SMS to
            param2: "Hello, I have fix it and is fine", // Message to be sent
        };
        myfunc.send(param,function(data) {
            //get the result here
            javascript: console.log(data);
        });
        };
        $(document).ready(test);
```

This is the function

```
myfunc= {
    send: function(param, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        cache: true,
        url: "http://example.com/test
        success: function(data) {
        callback.call(this, data);
        }
    });
    }
}
```

It is just a simple function and it works fine